# Thumbnail Image is getting recreated and its position is getting shuffled on scrolling ListView

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, android-asynctask, imageview

I know this is asked before and I have already searched a lot about this but could not get any proper answer on my issue.

I have created a list, the list gets filled with data that is coming from `JSON`. Now inside `getView()` method, I am inflating my custom row with data. Each row contains a `Thumbnail`, and I am creating each thumbnail from a different thread.

Now the problem is, everything is going well until I don't scroll my list. When I scroll my list, my `getView()` method is called continuously , and all thumbnail images are getting recreated and its position is getting shuffled. Once thumbnails are created I don't want to recreate them and also I want to maintain the order of my thumbnails.

**Can you please guys help me on this?**

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

My `getView()` method is:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row, parent,
                        false);
                viewHolder.titleText = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.titleText);
                viewHolder.thumbImage = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final String thumbnailURLString = mPostsList.get(position).get(
                    "thumb");
            createBitmapThread = (Thread) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            createBitmapThread = new MyThread(thumbnailURLString,
                    viewHolder.thumbImage);
            createBitmapThread.start();
            viewHolder.titleText.setText(title);

            return convertView;
        }
```

And the `Thread` class:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

        String mThumbURLString = null;
        ImageView mImageView = null;

        public MyThread(String thumbnailURLString, ImageView imageView) {
            mThumbURLString = thumbnailURLString;
            mImageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

                try {
                    URL newurl = null;
                    try {
                        newurl = new URL(mThumbURLString);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        // Options opts = new Options();
                        /*
                         * opts.inDither = true; opts.inInputShareable = true;
                         * opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true; opts.inPurgeable =
                         * true;
                         */
                        Log.e("", "INSIDE IMAGE DOINBG");
                        mBitmap = BitmapFactory
                                .decodeStream((InputStream) newurl.getContent());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mHandler.post(new MyRunnable(mImageView));
                } finally {

                }


    }

    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        ImageView mImageView = null;

        public MyRunnable(ImageView imageView) {
            mImageView = imageView;
        }

        public void run() {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please update your code, how you solved the problem. sorry, i am newbie and most of the things are going over my head here, i am stuck in same problem

Comment: I am successfully able to download images, it is just that they get shuffled in custom adapter's listview before all of them are downloaded. I just want to know how you stopped suffling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , here how i did a similar thing:

for each getView , create a new Fetching class and put it into a concurrent/synchronized stack . in the meanwhile , set the bitmap of the view to be empty (or anything else you wish) . you can also use caching instead.

the class will contain info of how to load the data (for example , the url of the bitmap) , the view to update , and the result of the fetching (for example , the bitmap itself) .

now , back to the getView, create&execute an asyncTask that will use a loop on the stack , each time it gets a Fetching class instance from the stack (once it's empty,the asyncTask will break the loop and finish) , check that the view that needs to be updated still needs the data (using its viewHolder) load the bitmap , set the result into the Fetching class , and pass it through the publishProgress() function.

in the onProgressUpdate method , do the same check as before using the Fetching class instance and the viewHolder . if all went well , update the view to have the bitmap that was fetched .

a nice yet complicated example of how to handle the same problem can be found [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html) .

Comment: The explanation you have provided is a bit diff to understand, or i am not able to visualize what you are saying. Can you give me some example? Or What changes I need to do in my current code?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and the suggestion above worked perfectly, finally - thanks!  Code snippets below:

My AsyncTask:

```
protected class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private View v;

    public LoadImageTask(View v) {
        super();
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "<onPostExecute> load image complete. ");            
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... addresses) {
        String response = "";
        Bitmap bm = null;
        for (String address : addresses) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            String name = getNameFromMDN(address);
            if (name != null && name.length() > 0) {
                // get contact ID from name
                long id = getContactID(name);

                if (id != 0) {
                    bm = getThumbnailForId(id);
                    if (bm != null && bm.getHeight() > 0) {
                        bm = resizeBitmap(bm);
                        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        Log.d(TAG, "set thumbnail for " + name + ", id: " + id);

                    }   
                }
            }

            // default icon
            if (bm == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "using default icon for mdn: " + address + ", name: " + name);
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.contact_big);


                /*String s = getContactNameByContactId(person, address);
                s = s.substring(0, 2);
                if (s.length() > 0 && !MDNUtil.isNumber(s)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "using dynamic icon for person: " + person + ", mdn: " + address + ", name: " + s);

                    icon.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);                    
                    iconText.setText(s);
                    iconText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    iconText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    // use generic icon
                    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.contact_big);
                }*/

            }



        }
        return "";
    }
```

then in the bindVew() of my CustomCursorAdapter:

```
LoadImageTask load = new LoadImageTask(v);
load.doInBackground(address);
```

update: what FINALLY WORKED was preventing the recycling of the views in the listview, in my custom cursor adapter:

```
       @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 500;
    }
```

Comment: update: this approach works for the thumbnail image, however, it doesn't work for additional images (the BadgeView I am using is re-used in the recycled views and visible while scrolling). not sure if this is a bug in the way ImageView re-uses views, but any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please upload the code for your adapter class, which you used, so that i can also try it. Because in my case, before all the images are downloaded they keep on shuffling, but after downloading they don't. Or if you can't upload code, can you please tell me why you returned hardcoded 500 in your getViewTypeCount() method? Sorry, i am a newbie.